# Изменения в базе данных каждые сутки python

Tags: python, база-данных, алгоритм

Подскажите алгоритм, который позволит каждый день делать конкретные изменения в базе данных.

Например, в каждые 00:00 в базе данных баланс пользователей увеличивается на 100 единиц

Comment: что то мне подсказывает, что подобных алгоритмов на просторах больше, чем пикселей на вашем мониторе..

Comment: в этом то вся проблема - нужно выбирать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать внешний модуль [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) для срабатывания действий в заданное время:

```
import time

# pip install schedule
import schedule

def inc_balances():
    # Работа с базой
    ...

schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(inc_balances)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```